# How to install Jenkins on same machine but different port?

Tags: jenkins

I installed Jenkins on machine using 8080 port. Now, I want to install on the same machine Jenkins but on 8090 port. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running it using the command line:

> java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8090

If you are running it in windows then you have to change the port in jenkins.xml which is by default under ProgramFiles/Jenkins

> --httpPort=8090

In Linux go to file:

> /etc/default/jenkins and add --httpPort=8090

Comment: if I change port like this, then can I access the both ports?

Comment: Yes both the service will run on the different ports.

Comment: it doesn't work, i changed the port with 8090 and now localhost:8080 can’t be reached

Comment: Now you have to hit localhost:8090

Comment: It's posibble to find a way for access localhost:8080 and localhost 8090 and on both servers to install different plugins?

Comment: Yes, every Jenkins have their own plugins. Are you trying to run two different Jenkins on the same server?

Comment: yes, I have only a server and  I want to use two ports for different scope

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191099/discussion-between-anurag-dwivedi-and-madalina).

Comment: Madalina were you able to run 2 jenkins server on same machine with different ports and probably different workspace paths? @anurag-dwivedi